# How to move entire PopupSubMenuMenuItem higher on aggregate menu

Tags: javascript, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

I'm curently working on some extension to the gnome-shell. I added a new Popup menu into aggregate menu in status area, but can't move it to the desired position. Tried `menu.moveMenuItem(item, position)`, but it moves only the "main" item, not the entire dropdown ([How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4he5B.png) - my PopupSubMenuMenuItem is named ThermalManagement, and submenu menu items starts from Optimized). What I need to do to move an entire submenu into specific position?

Code sample:

```
enable() {
    this._item = new PopupMenu.PopupSubMenuMenuItem('Thermal Management', true);
    this._item.icon.icon_name = 'applications-system-symbolic';
    let position = this._findMenuItemPosition(Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu._power.menu) + 1;

    this._optimizedOption = this._createOptimizedOption();
    this._item.menu.addMenuItem(this._optimizedOption);

    this._quietOption = this._createQuietOption();
    this._item.menu.addMenuItem(this._quietOption);

    this._coolOption = this._createCoolOption();
    this._item.menu.addMenuItem(this._coolOption);

    this._ultraPerformanceOption = this._createUltraPerformanceOption();
    this._item.menu.addMenuItem(this._ultraPerformanceOption);

    Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu.menu.addMenuItem(this._item);
    Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu.menu.moveMenuItem(this._item, position);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just passing the `position` as the second argument to `addMenuItem()`?

Comment: Wow - that was fast and easy. Thanks for that.